# Inverse operation in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get inverses of each bit in binary number. Suppose I have this binary number 
 **011** 
 and I should get 
**100**

Comment: It' s the ~ operator. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @traktor53, not really, because of the given length of the string ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom function and inverse every digit.

```js
var binary = '011',
    inversed = Array.from(binary, v => +!+v).join('');
    
console.log(inversed);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array from your string using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
2. Flip each `1` and `0` (a few methods provided below)
3. Merge them back into a single string with `join()`

```js
var a = '011';

//Arithmetic: 1-n
var result = Array.from(a, n=>1-n).join("");
console.log(result);

//Bitwise: n^=1
var result2 = Array.from(a,n=>n^=1).join("");
console.log(result2);

//Logical: +(!n)
var result3 = Array.from(a,n=>+(!+n)).join("");
console.log(result3);
```